# Data not passing to php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, geolocation

Getting trouble sending users geolocation through AJAX into a php file.

Here the code:

```
                    if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                            var pos = {
                                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                                lng: position.coords.longitude
                            };

                            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                            infoWindow.setContent('You are here');
                            map.setCenter(pos);
                            $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    data: pos,
                                    url: '/template-userslocation.php'
                                    });

                            },
                            function() {
                                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                            });                     

                   } else {
                           // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                           handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                   };
```

Have tried diferent ways to write data like: 
    `data: {pos}`, 
    `data:({pos})`,
    `data: {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude},`

And that it's the error that I get in `template-userslocation.php`:

> Notice: Undefined index: pos in /home/.../template-userslocation.php on line 7

---

SOLVED:

The problem was that I've been working in Wordpress and it has it own way to handle with javascript:

[here the info](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX)

Comment: check your browser console.

Comment: Well, that's what I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined at (index):384` @urfusion.

Comment: @Caesar are you including the jquery lib?

Comment: I have included it now in `header.php` file `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` but now I get `POST https://hooct.com/template-userslocation.php 404 ()` `send @ jquery.min.js:4  ajax @ jquery.min.js:4 (anonymous) @ (index):385` Now I'm really lost. @Lawrence Cherone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pos` is the name of the variable, from PHP it will not know that, it will only see `$_POST['lat']` and `$_POST['lng']`

**So use:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'pos': pos},
    url: '/wp-content/themes/atripby/template-userslocation.php'
});
```

Then from PHP access like:

```
$lat = isset($_POST['pos']['lat']) ? $_POST['pos']['lat'] : null;
$lng = isset($_POST['pos']['lng']) ? $_POST['pos']['lng'] : null;
```

Comment: have tried in `template-userslocation.php`: echo $pos = $_POST['pos'];`,`echo $lng = $_POST['lng']; echo $lat = $_POST['lat'];`. Same Notice. @LawrenceCherone.

Comment: @Caesar Try `$_POST['pos']['lat']`, if that fails jquery is not actually posting,  are you including the jquery lib? from your above comment it sounds like your not, or that your calling your code before init'ing the lib. You should also be checking your PHP vars before using e.g `$lat = isset($_POST['lat']) ? $_POST['lat'] : null` to avoid that warning.

Comment: With the jquery library written in header get the error that I wrote in the other comments. Have written: `$_POST['pos']['lat']` and before I wrote `$lat = isset($_POST['lat']) ? $_POST['lat'] : null;`. Get same `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /home/hooct781/public_html/wp-content/themes/atripby/template-userslocation.php on line 7`. thank you for your help I apreciate that @Lawrence Cherone

Comment: Have you tried, `/wp-content/themes/atripby/templat‌​e-userslocation.php` instead of `/template-userslocation.php`

Comment: Its also sending up as `pos[lat]:51.5412621
pos[lng]:-0.08813879999999999` so it will be accessed like `$_POST['pos']['lat']`

Comment: Accessable from https://hooct.com/wp-content/themes/atripby/template-userslocation.php as you can see.

Comment: Thank you again @Lawrence Cherone are following all your advices but still get same 404 in console error, changing the url to the complete one. The other comment that you write I'm not sure if I understand cause I am refreshing the page with code `$lat = isset($_POST['lat']) ? $_POST['lat'] : null;`  and `$_POST['pos']['lat']` still get same Notice. (NOTE. send me your adresse, I'will send you a cake for your help).

Comment: And the console in this page it's totally clean.

Comment: Your using `/home/hooct781/public_html/wp-content/themes/atripby/template-userslocation.php` use just `/wp-content/themes/atripby/template-userslocation.php`

Comment: Im watching ;p it now seems like some utf8 has creeped in to it `/wp-content/themes/atripby/templat‌​**e-userslocation.php`

Comment: Hahahaha so maybe a aspirine. Anyway I changed the link and still see the Notice. Or I'm not a homo sapiens or God has not forgiven me for the last saturday night. Anyway thank you, don't want to use more of your time. @Lawrence Cherone.

Comment: np, lol if you view the source your see some odd chars in the word `templat‌​e`, if you re-type that word it should work.

Comment: lol now its creeped into the word `p‌​hp`, you got some gremlins?

Comment: No way! hahahaha

Comment: Looks like its working now, got there in the end, *just dont change anything* ;p

Comment: How can you see things that I can't? I refresh the page and I don't see any echo coordenates. Still see in the page with the template `template-userslocation.php` the same Notice.

Comment: Im just using browser console, im getting 51.5412621 response from that file in console

Comment: So it seems now, that everything it's fine but I'm still in the ignorance watching my mistakes...